# How to sort formats in batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd

This is my first question in stack overflow, I hope I'm not breaking any rules, If I do, Just tell me.

I want to do a batch to open just TXT files, And send an error while opening other file format
Example: RTF

```
@echo off
rem I do some jokes while coding, As put name the name "randy" to a random variable :3
set randy=%RANDOM%
if exist %1 goto 1
echo msgbox ("Corrupt or unexisting file"),16,("Project1")>"%TMP%\FC%randy%SPEECH.vbs"
CScript "%TMP%\FC%randy%SPEECH.vbs" //nologo
erase /f /q "%TMP%\FC%randy%SPEECH.vbs"
exit

:1
rem I failed at this part, This part was supposed to filter the File format.
set filetype=%~1
echo %filetype%
pause>nul
if %filetype%=="*.png" goto 2 else goto notvalid
goto fail

:2
type %1
echo.
echo Press any key to close the file
pause>nul
exit

:fail
rem I also did a section if the code fails
echo msgbox("Oops, The code did not work"),16,("Project1")>"%TMP%\FC%randy%SPEECH.vbs"
CScript "%TMP%\FC%randy%SPEECH.vbs" //nologo
erase /f /q "%TMP%\FC%randy%SPEECH.vbs"
exit

:notvalid
rem If the format is wrong
echo msgbox("This format is not compatible with the app"),16,("Project1")>"%TMP%\FC%randy%SPEECH.vbs"
CScript "%TMP%\FC%randy%SPEECH.vbs" //nologo
erase /f /q "%TMP%\FC%randy%SPEECH.vbs"
exit
```

I hope what you can help me.

Comment: When you call the batch file, what parameters do you use. According to your program, the parameter should be `"*.png"` exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this at the start will branch to your routine on other filetypes:

```
@echo off
if /i not "%~x1"==".txt" goto :notvalid
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if /I "%filetype%"=="*.png" (goto 2) else goto notvalid
```

You need to use `"` double quotes and `()` parentheses properly, see [IF command](http://ss64.com/nt/if.html) (note that `goto fail` statement will not perform at all then); `/I` switch for case insensitive comparing. Compare:

```
==>if "*.TXT"=="*.txt" dir /B xxxx2.csv else dir /B xxx.csv

==>if /I "*.TXT"=="*.txt" dir /B xxxx2.csv else dir /B xxx.csv
xxxx2.csv
xxx.csv

==>if /I "*.TXT"=="*.txt" (dir /B xxxx2.csv) else dir /B xxx.csv
xxxx2.csv

==>
```

And I would recommend next improvement (check whether at least one parameter is supplied):

```
set "randy=%RANDOM%"
if "%~1"=="" goto :notvalid
set "filetype=%~1"
if exist %1 goto 1
```